# Leaflet displaying a single GeoJSON layer even though multiple are supplied

Tags: leaflet, geojson, jquery, cors

I have a simple Leaflet map and I am trying to display multiple point layers. I know this question has been asked quite a few times and I have tried every single solution but didn't work.

I get valid GeoJSONs (valid because I can display them individually) from two URLs. I can load the layers in my map and the `map.hasLayer()` returns true for both layers. But the map only displays the last layer, the first layer is not displayed.

I have tried different HTTP calls using Axios, jQuery, and plain XMLHTTPRequest too but the same behavior.

Logging the JSONs to the console shows that one layer has 0 features even though I am using the same code to load the second layer.

layer 1 console log

```
Object { type: "FeatureCollection", features: [] }
​
features: Array []
​
type: "FeatureCollection"
​
<prototype>: Object { … }
```

layer 2 console log

```
Object { type: "FeatureCollection", features: (5427) […] }
​
features: Array(5427) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, … ]
​
type: "FeatureCollection"
​
<prototype>: Object { … }
```

Is Leaflet overwriting on the features of the first layer?

Here is my code:

```
BASECOORDS = [51.96236, 7.62571];


var TILE_URL = "https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png";
var MB_ATTR = 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors';
mymap = L.map('llmap').setView(BASECOORDS, 13);
L.tileLayer(TILE_URL, {attribution: MB_ATTR}).addTo(mymap);

var ParkingLayer = null;
var TransLayer = null;

findNearby = function () {
    $.getJSON('/parking',
        function (geojsonPark) {
            ParkingLayer = L.geoJson(geojsonPark),
            console.log(geojsonPark)
            ParkingLayer.addTo(mymap);  
            return ParkingLayer
            });
};

findNearby2 = function () {
    $.getJSON('/trans',
        function (geojsonTrans) {
            TransLayer = L.geoJson(geojsonTrans),
            console.log(geojsonTrans)
            TransLayer.addTo(mymap);
            return TransLayer;
            });
};
findNearby()
findNearby2()
```

Comment: As you can see from the console log immediately after the first GeoJSON is read, GeoJSON is empty. There's obviously something wrong in the GeoJSON data.

Comment: @TomazicM I thought about the same. But if I reverse the order of drawing layers, i.e. I call the `findnearby2()` function before `findnearby()`, the effect is reversed. In that case I can see the other layer and not this one.

Comment: And the worst part is the console shows 0 errors too.

Comment: What do you see in the network section of the browser debugger? What gets returned from GeoJSON retrieval calls?

Comment: @TomazicM I did some more digging and the problem is, that the map is loaded before the layers can be drawn. If I refresh the page 2-3 times, the both layers are displayed. Is it possible to wait for the features to be loaded before loading the page?

Comment: P.s SetTimeout works perfectly. Thanks for your help @TomazicM

Comment: Please do not include your answer (solution) in the area reserved for the question. I think you should cut/paste it into a self-answer instead.

Comment: Are you running this map from server or local file system? If it's from server, this must be server problem. There is no such thing as "he map is loaded before the layers can be drawn." Map has to be defined/created first, then layers are added.

Comment: @TomazicM Yep sorry, I am new here. I posted as an answer. I have 6 big geojsons with 3000-4000 features each. I am running local version of postgres. though. The geojsons are not files, but postgis geometries and I convert them to geojsons. Sorry I should have mentioned this in the question. I guess I needed to wait for the request to be complete before executing the next one. But thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have 6 big GeoJSONs with 3000-4000 features each. I am running local version of PostgreSQL though. The GeoJSONs are not files, but PostGIS geometries and I convert them to GeoJSONs.

With `setTimeout`, I am now executing GeoJSON requests at different intervals and waiting for on request to be completed before executing the next query.

Now all the layers display correctly.

Comment: I edited answer to add info from comment.